# WordPress merging 2 separate queries

Tags: arrays, wordpress, loops, merge

I am currently building a custom query which gets the posts of a parent. The arguments for this query look like this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'page',
    'post_parent' => 5631,
    'meta_key'   => $key,
    'orderby'    => $orderby,
    'order'      => $order,
    'posts_per_page' => -1, 
);
```

This works as intended. However i would now like to add a search parameter like this:

`'s' => $maincat,`

into my argument list. But i need the search parameter to get posts that are not children of the parent '5631'.

Is this possible? I was thinking of maybe running 2 queries for both sets of results i want, then adding them into a new array and then looping through.

Is this way ok or is there a better approach?

Comment: is it a search page? `'s'` only accepts a string / keyword

Comment: im not sure why this matters?

Comment: I'm sorry I misunderstood - what exactly are you trying to accomplish?